# Ajax sending null string to controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm using an ajax call to try to send a string to my controller but it is returning null

My controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> CreateCarouselItem(string itemText){
    var newItem = new CarouselItem(itemText);
    await CarouselHelper.AddAndSaveAsync(newItem, _context);

    return itemText;
}
```

And My javascript

```
function FinishUp()
{
editor.disable();
var boxText = editor.getText();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Home/CreateCarouselItem',
    dataType: "text",
    data: { boxText },
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: console.log("it did not work"),
});

}
```

Comment: Sending up `boxText` and looking for `itemText`?

Answer (score 1):

The `dataType` option defines the expected *response* type, not the type of the data you're sending. For that, you need `contentType`, which needs an actual mime type, i.e. `text/plain` rather than just "text".

Then, you're sending an object instead of a string. If you just want the string then you should have just:

```
data: boxText
```

(without curly braces)

Finally, in your action, the default binding type is `x-www-form-urlencoded`, which expects a key value pair. You can change `data` again to:

```
data: 'itemText=' + boxText
```

Or you can bind from the body instead:

```
public async Task<string> CreateCarouselItem([FromBody]string itemText)
```

However, for that, I believe you also need to enable the text serializer in startup:

```
services.AddMvc(o =>
{
    o.InputFormatters.Add(new TextInputFormatter());
});
```

Comment: So I changed dataType to contentType and swapped "text" for "text/plain" as well as fixing data like you mentioned and its still coming back null. If i add the [FromBody] it becomes a 415 status code. And I'm not able to instantiate the TextInputFormatter because it's an abstract class

Comment: Sorry about that. I never actually had a need to accept plain text. You can simply create a concrete class that inherits from that, and then new up the concrete class. However, your best bet is to simply let it come as `x-www-form-urlencoded` and send `data: "itemText=" + boxText`.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the parameter which you would receive on action parameter is `itemText`, then you need to configure you data as `data: {itemText: boxText }`in ajax to bind the `itemText`:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Home/CreateCarouselItem',
        dataType: "text",
        data: {itemText: boxText },
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: console.log("it did not work"),
    });
```